# I want to create google script to show only the active user data in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a google script to show the data of the active user logging in the spreadsheet only because the sheet contains a lot of users and it's a confidential data so how can I do that?

```
function getActiveUser() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
  var numRows = 31; // Number of rows to process 
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B8 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7); // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  Logger.log(email); 
}
```

Comment: Is every user supposed to only read his data, or also populate the sheet?

Comment: Can't be done. One user, one Google Sheets **file**

Comment: Only read not edit

Answer (score 1):

If the sheet is only supposed to be read rather than edited by the users, you can link the script to an empty Spreadsheet, instead of the Spreadsheet containing all the user data, and modify the script in such a way that it copies from the Spreadsheet containing all the data only the user data into the User Spreadsheet. It would look like this:

```
function getActiveUser() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('your_Spreadsheet_ID').getActiveSheet(); 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
  var numRows = 31; // Number of rows to process 
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B8 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7); // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  //define a sheet where to copy only the user data
  var userSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var userRange = userSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7);
  // define the column in the sheet where the emails of the users is stored
  var userColumn=1;
  var k=1;
  //Copy all the rows that contain data of the user
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][userColumn-1]==email){
      for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
       userRange.getCell(k,j+1).setValue(data[i][userColumn-1+j])
      }
    k++;  
    }
  }  
}
```

However, keep in mind that this only works if you store the Spreadsheet on a shared drive. So, even if the user will not see the spreadsheet while running the script, he might still access it manually from the shared drive.
To solve this problem you would need to write an API and let it run by a Service Account.

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka, I found an error while running the code, "Bad value (line 2, file "code")", and please how can I link an empty spreadsheet with the script

Comment: You have to replace the placeholder 'your_Spreadsheet_ID' through your actual Spreadsheet ID (the one with all user data). As for the empty spreadsheet, I suggest that each of your users creates his own spreadsheet, goes to Tools->Script Editor and pastes the code I suggested you into his Code.gs file

Comment: So I will write the above code in the all users data sheet and then we will copy this script and paste it in an empty sheet so it will call the related user data right?

Comment: I did what you told me but I didn't find any output in the empty sheet

Comment: You don´t write the code in the data sheet, you paste it in the script file attached to the empty sheet. Put the empty sheet with the script file on a shared drive and ask each user to make a copy of it to his own drive.

Comment: As for the data sheet - all you have to do is to change the sharing settings in your Google Drive to make it accessible to all users who need to retrieve their data. Also, you have to incorporate it´s Id correctly and in quotes - replacing the 'your_Spreadsheet_ID placeholder. You can get the Id, when you open the data sheet in drive. If your url looks like this:  docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/THIS_IS_THE_SHEET_ID/edit#gid=0 , then the Id is located in the location of THIS_IS_THE_SHEET_ID

Comment: Have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zpr-ADHUaWUnUpVKuPw1vjjxfbiRmdpsViK2bv9jiys/edit?usp=sharing   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oksT5wrZXHr1bT9IbOMZsMZ-hXsZqIHIUB_bAjusgWA/edit?usp=sharing